# What material of a core put into the inductor would decrease the current?

Tags: transformer, ac, inductor, core

Consider the \$AC\$ circuit:

[image]

For various \$U\$ values set by the potentiometer, we have measured the current \$I\$ flowing through the circuit with and without core put inside the inductor \$L\$.

As a result we concluded that, without the core, the current was always bigger than with the core.

E.g.: for set \$U = 4V\$ the current with the core: \$I = 4.33 \; mA\$ and without the core \$ I = 26.9 \; mA\$.

The cylindrical-shaped core was made out of metal-alike material.

Questions:

- Given the fact that with the core the current was lower, what material could the core be made of? Ferromagnetic cores increase the current, right?
- What exactly does the `Atr` in the schematic stands for?

Comment: Probably autotransformer. Is this homework? Are you aware of permeability?

Comment: Not a homework, finished my physics lab and just curious afterwards. Reading about permeability right now, thanks.

Comment: Good. Look up permeability and Al value.

Comment: @weno I am split in feelings about your question. On the one hand, experiments like this are exactly the kind of thing about which you should *NOT* be told any answers. This is the kind of thing that can help you learn how to think ***about*** the world around you. There isn't really a right answer. In fact, it's possible that your own imagination might come up with something today that has never been published or discussed before and our world will be the better for it. Giving you the answer we have cuts short developing your imaginative powers. And that would be a sad loss.

Comment: @weno On the other, sometimes it's better to see the world standing on the shoulders of the giants who have come before you, too. So just telling you and letting you move on might be the better choice, too. Why do you think that a ferromagnetic core would increase the current? Can you explain your thinking about this? Why does it make sense? What's going on before adding the core and after, that makes you go this direction? Is it just something you read elsewhere and perhaps misinterpreted that is clouding your thinking now?

Comment: @weno There simply isn't a better author to read from, than Galileo Galilei. Of his many texts and letters and notes, the two most useful and accessible to us today in helping shape ***how to think*** are *Dialogue Concerning the Two Chief World Systems* and *Dialogues Concerning Two New Sciences*. Many other of his works are worth the time to read, as well. Newton was a powerhouse -- no argument. But Galileo's ability to conceive ways to test ideas was pure brilliance and worth the time trying to follow in his mental footsteps. This experiment would stimulate his mind. Yours too?

Comment: @weno Note that we don't read from the Greats in order to marvel at their conclusions. Most of their conclusions were wrong, anyway. We read from them to try and glimpse ***how*** they processed observation and ***how*** they then imagined novel ideas to try out and ***how*** they then tested them and cast them aside, one by one, tethering and bringing more closely together the surviving theoretical ideas to experimental results over time. Allow yourself this experiment as a segue to developing your own imagination and your ideas about how they may relate to your experimental results.

Comment: @weno Engineers take physical theory and use it to create practical things. An engineer can have theory handed to them on a silver platter and be fully satisfied to go exactly no further at all as they instead just go off and apply it. Physicists create new physical theories, question and tear down old ones, and create methods to test those newer thoughts against past experimentation and come up with future experiments to help differentiate between existing ideas. Are you a physicist or an engineer? You need to find out the answer, I think. This might be a good start on that.